# Event items with different CSS

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I have the following CSS to show a whole event as "completed".

```
   .afc-completed,
   .fc-agenda .afc-completed .fc-event-time,
   .afc-completed a {
       color: yellow;           /* text color */
       background-color: #6C3;  /* default BACKGROUND color   #36c */
       text-decoration: line-through;
    }
```

How do I write a CSS for only changing the fc-event-title only?
I saw my class afc-completed is added to the `<div>` element, but I don't find a solution to just change the title (fc-event-title) or the time.

Any help here?
Günter

Comment: you haven't got a fc-event-title there. However just put this at the bottom of your css: `.fc-event-title { background-color: red; }` or similar and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

@wsanville & @Thomas

I think that's not that simple, sorry.
Just defining what wsanville said will change for *all* events. The point is to change only for "completed" events.
For that I have

```
if (newEvent.completed != null) {
  newEvent.className = "afc-completed";
}
```

But that's going to the div and not to title only.
I think I need to add a class directly to/or instead of the '.fc-event-title' for just only those selected/completed events, and only to the title.
Here is a typical div:

```
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 8; left: 144px; width: 135px; top: 40px;"
   class="fc-event fc-event-hori fc-corner-left fc-corner-right afc-completed ">
   <a><span class="fc-event-time">15:15  - 16:15<br></span>
      <span class="fc-event-title">Fri Dille</span>
   </a>
   <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" unselectable="on" 
      style="-moz-user-select: none;">
   </div>
</div>
```

But the *newEvent.className* doesn't work like that!
Is there another possibility?

And I need more modifications to the event presentation, like additional icons or text with italic ... and different combinations of those 'options'.

Thanks for your help.
Günter

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is a working solution to solve for "important" and "completed" attributes of the event:

```
newEvent.className = ((newEvent.completed != null)? "afc-completed " : "") 
  + ((newEvent.priority != null) ? "afc-important " : "");
```

and

```
 .afc-completed .fc-event-title  {
    color: yellow; 
    background-color: #A6B5BC;   /*  grey */
    text-decoration: line-through;
   }
 .afc-important .fc-event-title  {
        color: #C00 !important;
        font-weight: bold !important;
   }
```

Thanks for helping ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you post some of your markup, I can give a better answer, but in the general case, you will need to add an additional rule to your stylesheet that applies to elements with the `fc-event-title` class. Something like this:

```
.fc-event-title
{
    color: #ff0000; /* change the color values to something more appropriate */
    background-color: #00ff00;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```